# System not booting with nVidia graphics card and NOMODESET in grub

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

Installed Linux Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Booted to black screen
Probably cause of NVidia Graphics Card
Tried to boot replacing quiet splash with nomodeset in the grub menu
and then:

[image]

Nomodeset mode boots to another dead end. This adding swap thing lasts for a couple of minutes and then goes to black screen.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Can you boot by adding this to the end of the linux line?: "nomodeset  grub_gfxmode=1280x1024x24"

Answer (score 0):

if you have an internal graphics card in addition to your nvidea graphics card you can try to temporarily remove the nvidea card (or disable it in BIOS/UEFI), install ubuntu, then the nvidea drivers and finally reactivate the nvidea card: see also this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/755667/538840

or you can try to use ubuntu 16.04, which may already include the relevant drivers.